# Stephen Hawking, RIP

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

No introduction is necessary. One of the great minds of our time is gone. Best known for his work, "[A Brief History of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Brief_History_of_Time)". Awards that he achieve include the Albert Einstein Award, the Wolf Prize, and the Copley Medal but unfortunately never won the Nobel.

https://www.theguardian.com/science/2018/mar/14/stephen-hawking-professor-dies-aged-76

Comment: Absolutely one of the greatest minds of our time. I'm surprised he lived this long with ALS. RIP

Comment: [WE SHOULD COMMEMORATE HIM BY SEEING MORE FILMS](https://xkcd.com/799/)

Comment: To the close-voter: This post is perfectly on-topic, we have an [in-memoriam] tag for this specific type of post. Please explain why this is "off-topic" here.

Comment: @Möoz - Because Stephen Hawking’s only connection to science *fiction* is a brief cameo on a TV show? Something virtually any big celebrity does.... In memorium posts are fine, but they are getting a little excessive.

Comment: @Adamant Then tell everybody to quit dying

Comment: The point is that we should not be using this site for just anyone....

Answer (score 20):

While he'll be remembered for his many great achievements in his life, and the popularisation of Science among the masses, Stephen Hawking will also be remembered for being the [only celebrity to cameo as themselves](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6556/68872) in *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, when he featured in a poker game with Data, Newton and Einstein.

Comment: I'm sure Newton and Einstein would have appeared as themselves if they could

Answer (score 7):

His work, along with that of his colleague, Kip Thorne, was the basis and inspiration of the much loved, *[**Interstellar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film))*

[image: Poster for the movie, "Interstellar". It depicts a man, Joseph Cooper (played by Matthew McConaughey). Cooper is standing in a rough and bleek icey cliff, probably in another world as he is wearing a spacesuit. The caption "The end of the world will not be the end of us" is displayed at the lower end of the poster, along with the movie's title, production and release information.]

Involving a plot where the main characters must find and understand the link between Einstein's '[General Relativity Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity)' and [Quantum Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics) - the theory popularly known as [***The Theory of Everything***](https://books.google.com.au/books/about/The_Theory_Of_Everything.html?id=JbRyIIeGLcIC&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y).

Answer (score 4):

May you keep on flying through the universe, in a constant journey of discovery that never ceases even though your time on this small planet has ended. We that are left behind will not forget your contributions to human understanding of the structure of the greater universe.

As for all the wagers you had going with colleagues about the results of their work, I'm sure they'll honour their debts somehow, with all those bottles of wine they owe you.

Comment: That last bit is actually true, btw.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of good articles about his cameos, in addition to his numerous appearances as himself in various science shows.

http://www.radiotimes.com/news/tv/2018-03-14/stephen-hawking-best-tv-cameos/

- Futurama
- Simpsons
- Star Trek: Next Generation
- The Big Bang Theory
- Hitchhiker's Guide
- Monty Python
- Late Night with Conan - Twigging Jim Carrey

And, as always, a list of his appearances can be found [at his IMDB listing](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0370071/).